# Normalization of coordinates to closest route

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

In my application I receive GPS coordinates which I use to draw route using `HERE`'s `calculateRoute` method and polyline. But results are poor and rarely accurate probably due to low accuracy of the measurements.

**Example of this behavior on the picture below - actual route should be only on the biggest, diagonal street.**

So my idea to circumvent this problem is to first 'normalize' these coordinates by approximating them to nearest street.

My question is: does `HERE API` provides such method and if so what it is called?
I have searched documentation and googled for it but to no avail.

As a last resort I can switch my whole app to `Google Maps` which I know that have the method in its API to do exactly what I need.

If this will help anyone to answer this question, here are my parameters for drawing this route:

```
    mode: 'fastest;truck',
    representation: 'display',
    routeattributes: 'waypoints,shape,summary',
    maneuverattributes: 'direction',
    waypoints: [/* too much to show here*/],
    avoidLinks: '',
    avoidSeasonalClosures: true,
    alternatives: 1,
```

[image: Route drawn with actual GPS data and <code>calculateRoute</code> function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HERE Route matching API is for what you want to achieve.
Check out this developer documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html